# How are one liners not blocked before being asked?

Tags: discussion, bug, questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65359439/open-a-folder-first-to-edit-configurations) somehow was allowed to be asked and stayed open for 5(!!) long minutes. Why didn't the in-place filter take action? Is this a bug? Are one-liners intentionally allowed?

Since the question has been deleted, here's an image for those who can't see the question.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to say that there's no fix 5 years later too?

Comment: Things take 6 to 8 here to implement / fix ...

Comment: There we go: Another one https://stackoverflow.com/q/65359699/11930602

Comment: Do you suggest we impose a minimum amount of paragraphs to a question? That \n does not seem \n like a great \n idea.

Comment: No, that is not what I suggest

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 then what is the issue with one liners?

Comment: I actually mean to ask the same, though exactly other way around. When are one-liners useful?

Comment: Actually, I have asked a question that was literally one line. It's very rare of course, but it is possible.

Comment: Well yeah, but in that case, I think we need to impose at least rep restrictions

Comment: Yeah, I though the rep restrictions would cover this case. Apparently not :(

Comment: If people were blocked from asking them, they would simply add nonsense text to get around the quality filter. This can often be seen in code-only questions in which, for example, some code is left unformatted or they are adding gibberish or text saying it was added to get around the quality filter. I once saw someone even pasting parts of a movie script into their question.

Comment: @JeanneDark *If people were blocked from asking them, they would simply add nonsense text to get around the quality filter* That is because computers are stupid and dumb; and people can use these methods to get around any restrictions. But then again, that is why we have human mods :)

Comment: Certainly we shouldn't be allowing questions that are only a few words long and match the title exactly with no additional content...

Comment: @TylerH On the other hand, if you have an actual great, high quality question that is one line, it makes perfect sense to use that one line as both the title and the question body.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That's interesting. I don't recall seeing a high quality question that had the same one line in both the title and the body. Do you happen to have an example of that?

Comment: @cigien I don't, and to be honest, I can't imagine a lot of great one-line questions. But I do think that if a question is so succinct it can be one line, it makes sense to just use the same text as the title.

Comment: Instead of "does the quality filter work", perhaps we should rather ask "does the quality filter *exist*".

Comment: @MarkRotteveel *maybe*, but that's a big 'if'. Notice I also didn't say 'one line' but 'a few words long'. The question in the screenshot could more than double in length and still be one line.

Comment: One-liners usually refer to code or command lines, but is there (unofficially) a rule for the number of paragraphs or sentences?

Comment: @TylerH That's not a bug. This is possible on meta to close equal bug reports or feature requests. Those don't need answers to be solved, thus requiring answers to be an eligible dupe target is not useful for meta sites.

Comment: @Tom Sure they do. Every dupe should eventually point back to an answer or response. At the very least, such unanswered questions, if not deserving an answer, should have a [meta-tag:status-*] tag to indicate an official position.

Comment: Wait, we have automatic quality filters?

Comment: @TylerH *"At the very least, such unanswered questions, if not deserving an answer, should have a \[meta-tag:status-] tag to indicate an official position"* then feel free to request that. It makes not much sense to require an official response until you can close a reported bug report for the same issues, but we'll see how your request will end up.

Comment: @Tom it makes sense when you consider at least one question should receive an answer from someone (anyone) explaining how this is likely a bug, or not a good idea for a feature request, etc. That question can then become a canonical, go-to location for discussing the idea, and duping questions makes sense. Closing a question in Dec 2020 as a dupe of a similar question from 2015 that has a fairly high score and yet no answers by anyone is... counterproductive.

Comment: Don't really short questions end up in the 'low quality posts queue' automatically?

Comment: As I have already stated, I do not agree with @JeffUK (sorry about that Jeff :) ). Can we have an answer from a moderator as to what exactly went wrong when filtering the question, seeing that we *have* a filter?

Answer (score 13):

Just because a question is short doesn't mean it is necessarily bad. Removing short questions automatically would sometimes remove good questions, which **is** bad for the site.

In fact many of the first few pages of [highest rated questions ever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Votes) are very concise:

[What is the difference between 'git pull' and 'git fetch'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-is-the-difference-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch) 1 line, 12K Upvotes, and the title matches the body text exactly.

[Can comments be used in JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244777/can-comments-be-used-in-json) 1 line, 8K upvotes, and fewer words than the example in this question.

[How do I undo the most recent local commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git) 2 lines 22K Upvotes. Honourable mention, currently #2 ranked question of all time.

Comment: Can you provide any recent questions please? All the questions you have linked seem to be very old, especially from the time when SO wasn't the first help forum people went to, basically meaning, it was rare for a complete noob to post on SO. Now-a-days, the quality of the questions has declined with popularity as even newbies have access to SO. Don't get me wrong please :)

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 here you go: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1349221

Comment: @rene, not many have more than 1 votes. Not to mention, the query somehow returned questions with DVs too. Something wrong I did perhaps?

Comment: @rene correction: most are DVed or 0 scored

Comment: The system works. There are 129 questions in that specific resultset. I'm sure we can clean those up by moderation rather then waiting for 6 to 8 weeks to get a horrendous filter implemented.

Comment: @rene, I ain't very good at SQL. What query do I write to get only the UVed ones out of those 129?

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 this one barely runs but an `inner join posts on posts.id = pht.postid and score > 0` might work. Maybe reduce the set to only this year.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 that's irrelevant, if any of these questions had been asked on here for the first time today they would still be good on-topic questions; and the proposed filters would have stopped them being asked.

Comment: @JeffUK The point is that those low-hanging fruit questions have already been asked, and as such the likelihood of good one-liners being asked in 2020 is far lower.

Comment: @IanKemp it may be less likely, but as new features are added to existing tools and languages, or new tools and languages are created, similar 'simple' questions will remain on-topic. So the answer stands "We don't delete one line questions automatically because they are sometimes good questions". (Assuming a new 'fnord' command was added to git today.Q:"what is the difference between git 'pull' and git 'fnord'" should NOT be deleted automatically tomorrow)

Comment: Are the examples good questions? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask says to research before asking, and share the research already done. Those questions seem pretty poor questions (even if upvoted). I don't see any effort from the OP's side to at least open the docs and say what is not clear in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch and https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull, or if they even tried the commands and saw inconsistent behaviour (for the first example); can't see if the OP of the second example tried to read https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259, etc...

Comment: Isn't allowing one-liners optimizing for the 1% case, not the 99% case?

Comment: @Jofre that is because most people use this page to not read stuff. If I wanted to know the difference between pull and fetch, I would google "What is the difference between git fetch and git pull" and arrive here. Also for JSON. I wouldn't bother reading an RFC for such a question whether there is a possibility to place comments.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs we're not 'optimising for' one-liners; we're saying banning them outright is damaging.  'optimising for' them would be to give them some special preferential treatment.

Comment: The most "recent" question in that list was posted in May 2009. In fairness you should post the dates, the answer is giving a false impression as to what makes a question posted *today* acceptable. Please define "large proportion" For example is that more or less than 40%?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I provided a link to both the list of the highest rated questions ever and each question I used as an example,  the dates are clearly listed!  However I feel that ONE example of a good question that is also a one-liner is good evidence enough that the slight inconvenience of having to moderate the bad ones is outweighed by the danger of automatically removing good questions.  Unless there is evidence that one-line questions specifically over-burden the moderation queues.

Comment: That said, 'large proportion' is weasly, fixed that bit!

Comment: The dates are *not* listed in the answer.

Comment: Defending one-line questions should only be used  in cases where a post risked deletion because they no longer conformed to the site's current standards (something which has happened on EL&U). Preserving the OP and its answers would then be justifiable and appropriate. But how many of those questions would remain open if posted today? I suspect a few would be immediately closed for lack of research/effort.

Comment: We can do this instead. We can notify the mods of really short posts from new/low-rep users and then, mods being human, can decide the particular course of action.

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 you mean like the 'Low Quality Posts Queue' does already?

Comment: I'm a mod, and I don't want to be *notified* of one-sentence "questions". I want them blocked. A good question by Stack Overflow standards requires more than 1 sentence of explanation. If you find the rare question that doesn't, add more explanation anyway.

Comment: @CodyGray the site should be optimised for users, not for moderators.

Comment: Of course: users who want to read and answer high-quality questions.