# Why don't duplicate targets on meta need to have answers?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, meta

Recently this question [How are one liners not blocked before being asked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403821), was asked and closed as a duplicate of [Does the quality filter work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284764). The question is indeed a duplicate, but the interesting thing is that the target doesn't have any answers. I was quite surprised to learn that this is possible, since that is different from how it works on main. There are several good reasons for not being able to do this on main of course.

The [MSE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47635/800395)  describes the rule like this:

> On most sites, voting to close a question as a duplicate of another post means that the same question has been asked before and has already been answered. On meta sites, however, ...
>
> ... if the same feature has been suggested in the past, but received no answers, it may be closed as a duplicate. To that end, the system will allow users to choose an unanswered question as a target, which is ordinarily not allowed on main Q&A sites.

For meta questions with the primary tag being [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), I can sort of see the rationale for allowing this. However, this has the effect of allowing all meta questions to be closed as a duplicate of an unanswered question regardless of the primary tag, and I'm not sure this is always a good idea.

Just a thought, but for [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions where the target is relatively old, users might be more likely to see and answer the new question if it were open. Case in point, the [new question about quality filters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403821) is currently only one vote away from being reopened. I would like to cast that final reopen vote, but first I'd like to understand the rationale behind why the question could even be closed in the first place, to ensure that I don't vote to reopen a post that should remain closed.

I've looked around a bit, and I haven't been able to find any discussion of why this is different on meta, or any discussion on whether this is always a good thing. If this discussion has been brought up before in a meta post, I'd be very happy to close this one. Unless the target hasn't received any answers, in which case I would be considerably less happy about having to do that :)

Comment: I would argue it's because both are bringing up the same issue. Also, people are significantly more reluctant to post answers on Meta due to how generous it is with downvotes. That's why this is a comment, because I may be wrong.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 That's interesting. I would have thought users would be even more wiling to post answers on meta, since there is no associated rep loss for downvotes.

Comment: Well, also Meta is a lot more opinion based than Stack Overflow. And downvotes still feel bad even if you lose no reputation!!

Comment: @M-Chen-3 Yes, I don't disagree that it feels bad, even if it's valuable feedback.

Comment: Hey... this is a meta-meta-question! (I'm curious to know the answer because I experienced this kind of meta-closure in the past).

Comment: @JeanneDark Not really. I've stated that I know the rule that lets posts be closed like that. I'm asking *why* the rule exists, and starting a discussion about whether it's a good idea to always use that ability, particularly for [discussion] questions. The suggested Q&A doesn't really cover that. I'll try to edit this question to make that clearer.

Comment: That answer by an SE employee doesn't answer your question? It might not fully cover [discussion] questions, but it seems impractical for several reasons (eg. tags can change) to make an exception for questions tagged [discussion] so they couldn't be closed as duplicates of unanswered questions (else everyone would add that tag to their question to immunize them from duplicate closure).

Comment: Like I said, not really. Also, it's not clear to me why the answer being by an SE employee is relevant. Interestingly, your second sentence is a perfectly reasonable answer to this question, that is not applicable to the suggested Q&A, which suggests that this may not in fact be a duplicate.

Comment: Because Meta was graciously made an exception to this absolutely *horrible* policy when it was announced on the main sites. There are literally no good reasons for not being able to close a question as a duplicate on the main site. Duplicates aren't defined by the answers; they're defined by the questions.